# How to sum up the number of matches in re.findall from a large corpus?

Tags: python, regex

```
for file in os.listdir(working_dir):
   with open(os.path.join(working_dir, file), 'r',encoding='utf8') as f:

       IVP_pattern = '\(VP[a-zA-Z0-9_\s.+-]+\((^NP|VP|S|SBAR|PP)'

       text1 = ' '.join(f.read().replace(')', '').replace('\n', '').split()

       count_IVP = len(re.findall(IVP_pattern, text1)

       print(count_IVP)
```

I wrote a Regex to find all the matches in my text. Len(match) shows the total number of matches in each text. I want to know how I could sum up all the number from each count_IVP and get a total with Python code. The print result shows each distinct number of a sub-text, as follows:

```
<class 'int'>
99
<class 'int'>
85
<class 'int'>
23
<class 'int'>
14
<class 'int'>
57
<class 'int'>
85
<class 'int'>
6
<class 'int'>
7
<class 'int'>
4
<class 'int'>
12
```

Each result displays the total number of matches in a sub-text. I would like to know how to use Python code to add them up and get a total.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it right: You want to add all of those counts to an accumulated sum?

Comment: Can't you define global variable `ivp_total`, and then in each loop iteration do `ivp_total+=count_IVP` ?

Comment: I don't know if I follow. Are you asking for how you can sum numbers?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the total, add `total = 0` before your for loop and before your print statement add `total += count_IVP` so that it will add your count during each loop. Then after your loop, add another print statement to print your total.